# How to do job while the application is exiting in UWP?

Tags: uwp, exit

I have to do some cleanup job while my application is exiting.

[image]

My windows version.

[image]
Capabilities in package.appxmanifest

[image]
But the event Exiting and Closed never triggered.
I do not know the problem. please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UWP, there is a special event for window closing: [SystemNavigationManagerPreview.CloseRequested](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.preview.systemnavigationmanagerpreview.closerequested?view=winrt-19041)

If you want to use this event, you need to add a special capability:

**package.appxmanifest**

```xml
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10" 
         xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest" 
         xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10" 
 
xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
         IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap">

<Capabilities>
...
  <rescap:Capability Name="confirmAppClose"/>
...
</Capabilities>

</Package>
```

After this, you can register for the event callback:

```cs
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    Windows.UI.Core.Preview.SystemNavigationManagerPreview.GetForCurrentView().CloseRequested +=
        async (sender, args) =>
        {
            args.Handled = true;

            // Do something

            App.Current.Exit();
        };
}
```

When your app window closing, this event will be triggered and you can perform some save operations. (Prior to this, you must set `args.Handled` to **true** to prevent the app window closing).

Comment: I can not find "confirmAppClose" in my Capabilities list