# Preventing UWP from shutting down by pressing ‘B’ button on XBOX – XAMARIN

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp

There is a post in stackoverflow that covers my research in this matter so far: [How to do job while the application is exiting in UWP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64552670/how-to-do-job-while-the-application-is-exiting-in-uwp/72986867#72986867)

I found this solution in several searches about the preventing UWP from closing and it works, I know I’ll have to ask for approval before I submit my app to Windows Store to use Restricted capabilities to use it, but it is ok.

But the point is: I’m writing an app to run in Android, iOS and UWP platforms, in UWP the ability of the user to close the app in a PC is quite alright but closing the app in XBOX by accidentally press button B in the Gamepad control is a very annoying issue that I want to prevent!

The post mentioned before cover the problem to UWP app in a pc, with is not an issue for me because if the user clicks the X in the up-right corner of the window it alright that the app closes, but if the user press B button of XBOX controller accidentally and the app closes immediately, it is a very rude event of user experience, and I want that out of my app.

So, the post I mentioned before works fine for a PC, but it does not work at all in an XBOX series S. My question is how can I solve this issue? I’m sure that is not a UFO thing because every game bought in the store have this issue solved!
How can I do the same?

Answer (score 1):

I figure it out: preventing XBOX button B is about disable back button not about intercept a close request.
So, the only thing is needed to be done is to add:

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed() => yes;
```

to the page where the back button is meant to be disables

Comment: protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed() => true; (I use the yes constant as true)

Comment: Apparently, this only seems to apply to Xamarin - I'm looking for a solution to this that works in straight C# and there's no suitable method to override when using that approach.